# Specified cast is not valid in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I got the following code:

```
var model = new List<LogModels>();

while (reader.Read())
{
     var logContent = new LogModels(
         (int)reader["id"],
         (string)reader["response"],
         (string)reader["language"],
         (string)reader["country"],
         (string)reader["location"],
         (string)reader["os"],
         (string)reader["browser"],
         (string)reader["type"],
         (DateTime)reader["date"]
      );

     model.Add(logContent);
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Speed Services.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.
```

Image: https://i.gyazo.com/adf04b8e271bb53c93303d5774a48f80.png

My model (LogModels) looks like this:

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string response { get; set; }
public string language { get; set; }
public string country { get; set; }
public string location { get; set; }
public string os { get; set; }
public string browser { get; set; }
public string type { get; set; }
public DateTime date { get; set; }
```

Does someone know what the issue could be since I can't seem to find the problem?

Comment: Full exception message is more useful than 1000 images but I'd guess one of those fields are not of the type you expect (message will tell you which one...) Of course I'm talking about reader object (which I suppose is a DB DataReader), not your View Model class LogModels.

Comment: You should narrow down which one is failing. I'd bet either `id` or `date`.

Comment: Have you checked if the `date` of the current record is null? Maybe try changing the `DateTime` to a nullable type (for example `DateTime?`)

Comment: How exactly can I check which one is causing the problem? I am new to Visual Studio. This is the database table: https://i.gyazo.com/3471b22ad642b7e12aab6fd2ac4111ab.png Nothing seems to be null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var model = new List<LogModels>();

while (reader.Read())
{
     var logContent = new LogModels(
         Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"].Tostring()),
         (string)reader["response"],
         (string)reader["language"],
         (string)reader["country"],
         (string)reader["location"],
         (string)reader["os"],
         (string)reader["browser"],
         (string)reader["type"],
         Convert.ToDateTime(reader["date"].Tostring())
      );

     model.Add(logContent);
}
```

casting problem because of integer or datetime value.
`(int)reader["Id"]` instead of `Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"].Tostring())`
`(DateTime)reader["date"]` instead of `Convert.ToDateTime(reader["date"].Tostring())`